# asp.net mvc 5 error on trying to register at newly created website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

fresh os, fresh vs 2015, all i do is create new mvc project with individual authentication and once i try to register it give me that error (i edit nothing, i delete nothing)

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 153:            { Line 154:                var user = new
>   ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email }; Line
>   155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,
>   model.Password); Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded) Line
>   157:                {
>
> Source File: c:\users****\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Controllers\AccountController.cs
>   Line: 155
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]

Comment: I have this same issue except in VS 2019 and I have tried the posted answers but they did not work for me. Does anyone have any additional potential solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem, I have found a solution to it .. problem exists in ConnectionString , change it from :

```
connectionString="Data Source(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20160303101342.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20160303101342;Integrated Security=True"
```

To :

```
  connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Data Source=YourServerName"
```

And it will work without any other changes

Answer (score 1):

Did you created database using migrations?

If not, open package manager console in VS(Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)

In command line you have to enable migrations with command.

> Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations

after that run command

> Update-Database

and start project.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: it's not solved and as far as i know that i only need to use migrations when i edit a code first database but i've not even touched the code yet, i was trying it out of the box and it wasn't working

Comment: After hours of struggle and several solutions attempted. This one worked for me, but only on the second try. I wonder why this isn't done by default. Surely everyone who downloads Visual Studio and start a ASP.NET MVC project doesn't hit this roadblock. Is this dependent on environment?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [these tutorial](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/).
You need to enable migration, add first migration with your models and update database.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tutorial either skipped the database creation part or is behind the latest VS 2013 templates. The Databases is missing when you create a new MVC project. In addition, the tutorial register a user via username while the project wants you to use email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Go to package Manager Console

step 1 Run Below command

```
enable-migrations
```

Step 2 Run below command

```
add-migrations InitialModel
```

Step 3 and last run the command

```
update database
```